# The memory usage in oracle server when using jdbc setfetchsize

Tags: oracle, jdbc

When I use setFetchSize() method for a select statement for example

> select * from tablename

for a large table in oracle JDBC driver. It actually limit the memory usage in the JDBC client.

However, what I am curious is that will this statement cause oracle server stores all the rows in the server memory ignoring the fetch size which leads to an OutOfMemory error on the Oracle Server?

Comment: Short answer is no ... I'll leave the long and complicated answer of describing what Oracle stores when it opens a cursor and how the result set is fetched in batches of rows to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

> However, what I am curious is that will this statement cause oracle server stores all the rows in the server memory ignoring the fetch size which leads to an OutOfMemory error on the Oracle Server?

No, Oracle, processing the cursor(select), will not get all the rows of a particular table at once in memory.
Oracle has a complex and secure architecture.
Oracle has a number of criteria for evaluating a table : "large" or "small".

When using the cursor normally (sql engine), it will not be possible to get OutOfMemory on the server process.

For example, if your server-side code processes data through pl / sql collections, you can get data from your server process without specifying the limit for retrieving rows, and if the server process reaches the PGA limit(PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT), the process will crash(after  all resources occupied by the process will be freed).

This theme is not simple, from the point of view of explaining the mechanism of the database in one post)

If there is an interest to understand in more detail, then I think the following links may be useful.

Additional links:

[SQL Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL175)

[Working with Cursors](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-cursors)

[Oracle Relational Data Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/oracle-relational-structures.html#GUID-54C48ABE-E589-428A-849F-B8746C9D276A)

[Oracle Data Access](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/oracle-data-access.html#GUID-521F93E0-891B-454F-9BA0-C2D213FE3481)

[Oracle Database Storage Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/oracle-database-storage-structures.html#GUID-B679FE3E-8FC1-404C-A368-5A4AC0553664)

[Process Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/process-architecture.html#GUID-85D9852E-5BF1-4AC0-9E5A-49F0570DBD7A)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this answer and links. I think I have concluded the answer by the following link.